# How to set prefix before string generation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i have a function that generates random string, but i want to set 3 prefix's and system to choose random prefix of thoses specified? The prefix's is 001, 002 or 003. For example when i try to generate string i want my system to choose one prefix of these that i specify.

```
public function generateRandomNumber($length) {

    $prefix = '001';
    //$prefix = '001';
    //$prefix = '001';
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomNumber = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomNumber .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $prefix . $randomNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of prefixes and pick a random one using [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

```
$prefixes = ['001', '002', '003'];
$prefix = $prefixes[array_rand($prefixes)];
```

Comment: If this solved your question please consider marking this as the answer so other users might find this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function generateRandomNumber($length) {

    $prefix = array(001,002,003);
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomNumber = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomNumber .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $prefixes[array_rand($prefixes)].$randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: `array_rand` outputs the index of an array element, so the prefix here will be `0`, `1` or `2`.

Comment: Yes result of this code is 0,1 or 2 and 6 random digits answer number 3 is the right way.